# MySQL: Insert records virtually in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I get a set of result as follows

```
C1     C2   C3
10     2    T
10     3    E
10     6    S
```

I want my SELECT query in such a way that resultant records may look like

```
C1     C2   C3
10     2    T
10     3    E
10     4
10     5
10     6    S
```

where there is a blank line for the missing records. Couldn't figure out the same.

Original query: `select C1, C2,C3 from Table`

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: @D-Shih It is 5.7

Comment: Would you mind to update your mysql version? there is a solution from cte recursive, but it need to use mysql version upper 8.0

Comment: and what is the solution :-|

Comment: So you are fulling the in the range of C2, are its bounds known ahead of time? Showing the original query would help derive the new query.

Comment: Have added original query but the won't help since it is simply a SELECT statement and the data now I need will be including records that are missing from c2

Comment: @MateyJohnson I add an answer for mysql 8.0 which support `cte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mysql version upper than 8.0, you can try to use cte RECURSIVE make a calendar table then do `outer join`

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  C1 int, 
  C2 int,
  C3 varchar(5)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (10,2,'T');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (10,3,'E');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (10,6,'S');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
    SELECT C1,MIN(C2) minC2,MAX(C2) maxC2
    FROM T
    GROUP BY C1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT C1,minC2 +1,maxC2
    FROM CTE
    WHERE minC2+1 <= maxC2
)
SELECT t1.C1,t1.minC2,t2.C3
FROM CTE t1 LEFT JOIN T t2 on t1.minC2 = t2.C2
ORDER BY C1,minC2;

| C1  | minC2 | C3  |
| --- | ----- | --- |
| 10  | 2     | T   |
| 10  | 3     | E   |
| 10  | 4     |     |
| 10  | 5     |     |
| 10  | 6     | S   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iHxo7bXCRezZi4DWoDhjeT/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table of sequential numbers in your database, and then use an outer join to fill in the missing row values for C2. 
It will be very useful for other queries as well, and takes very little space.

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (Number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO Numbers (Number) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6) ...
```

And then:

```
SELECT T.C1, N.Number AS C2, T.C3 
FROM Numbers AS N LEFT OUTER JOIN T ON T.C2 = N.Number
WHERE N.Number BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(C2) FROM T) AND (SELECT MAX(C2) FROM T)
ORDER BY C2;
```

HTH